# Can I recover memory allocated to ccache (compiler cache)?

Tags: android, c++, android-source, cyanogenmod, ccache

I have been building [LineageOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LineageOS) and [AOSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)#Development) ROMs for over a year now.

A build for me takes about eight hours on my PC and I know using ccache can speed things up for me.
But I have read on LineageOS's website and XDA that you cannot recover the space once it has been allocated.

I really don't want to lose 50 to 75 GB of disk space forever.

This might be silly, but just to be sure, is there really no way to recover that space? Even formatting?

[Link to LineageOS website](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/bacon/build#build-lineageos-and-lineageos-recovery)

Comment: It's not gone forever - that's just stupid speak from someone who obviously does not know what they are talking about.

Comment: ccache is using regular files to store cached objects. See https://ccache.samba.org/manual/latest.html#_configuration for configuration options, you can configure cache directory, maximum size and other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is:

[`ccache -C`](https://ccache.samba.org/manual/latest.html#_options)

This will delete everything in the cache; I don't know why that page says the memory is gone forever, as `ccache --help` shows you the flags.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'll start using it. my score is less than 15 and my vote won't show